# Markov process with conditions

Tags: bayesian, interaction, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am trying to model a basketball game using play by play data. Each team has a transition matrix representing what they will do next on offense and defense in any given time remaining in the game.

Problem I have is establishing the interaction between teams. How do I account for a different transition matrix based on whether the other defense is good or bad?

In a way, each transition's likelihood changes due to a variety of factors. Surely I don't need to do some sort of chain of regressions or models do I?

I'm a little new to this, so I am looking for the right modeling approach.